# how to dynamically rename html link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a link to a user profile by clicking a link labelled "user_id" with this code:

```
<p>Tags: <%= raw feed_item.usertags.map(&:user_id).map { |t| link_to t, usertag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></p>
```

I am trying to make the link appear as the user_name the user_id link points to. Any ideas?

Edit:

User model:

```
attr_accessible :name(aka user_name), :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Micropost model:

```
attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :usertag_list
has_many :usertaggings
has_many :usertags, through: :usertaggings
belongs_to :user
```

Usertag model:

```
attr_accessible :user_id *actually a string field not integer*
has_many :usertgaggings
has_many :microposts, through: :usertaggings
```

Comment: Could you describe models involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strikes me as strange that you're using `usertag_path(t)`, when `t` is a user id. If you want the link to the user page, then that would be `user_path(t.user)`, no?

Anyway I think this should work:

```
<p>Tags: <%= raw feed_item.usertags.map { |t| link_to t.user.name, user_path(t.user) }.join(', ') %></p>
```

Comment: I have the link to the user page. The issue is that the link reads e.g. [link](101) as opposed to [link](John smith) where John Smith has user_id:101. Clicking 101 or John Smith redirects to the correct profile.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my point was that it shouldn't work: `usertag_path` returns a route for usertags, not users. In any case did the code I posted work?

Comment: The code did not work. The code I am using is a modified version of http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast

Comment: What about this then?: `<p>Tags: <%= raw feed_item.usertags.map { |t| link_to t.user.name, user_path(t.user_id) }.join(', ') %></p>`

Comment: No luck either with error "undefined method `user' for "87":String". I have edited the usertag model by adding "has_one :user: since each tag is an alias for a user. This did not solve the problem either.

Comment: Are you sure you're copying what I wrote exactly? Note that I've taken out the `map(&:user_id)` part of the code. Please copy exactly what I wrote and see if it works.

Comment: did not work with error "undefined method `user' for #<Usertag:0x3d73460>"

Comment: Have you added the `has_one :user` line to the `Usertag` model? If so then it should have a method `user`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22265/discussion-between-okyekyein-and-shioyama)

Comment: Not sure you're checking the chat, but just to repeat: that should be `belongs_to :user`, not `has_one :user`. Can you try that and see if it works?